# Orchard 1.8.x build Precompiled with Command Prompt for VS2013 gives errors on .ts files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, command-prompt, orchardcms-1.8

When I build a precompiled  version of Orchard 1.8 with the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013:

```
build precompiled
```

there are 17 errors thrown. These errors are all about TypeScript files.

Each error is shown in the Command Prompt in the following way

```
Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Azure.MediaServices\Orchard.Azure.MediaServices.csproj([NUMBER],[NUMBER]): error : "None" element name for include "Scripts\[FILENAME].ts" should be "Content". [[PATH_TO_ORCHARD]\Orchard.proj]
```

When I open the Orchard 1.8 project in Visual Studio 2013 and build the entire solution there are no errors thrown.

What do I have to do to build a precompiled version of Orchard 1.8.x with Command Prompt for VS2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Azure modules aren't used in the project I removed these projects and related test projects from the solution before building a precompiled version.

Comment: How did you remove the projects, i am trying in the orchard.sln but when building keep getting the errors and those projects copied across. <br> Did you just delete them from the Orchard.Web/Modules altogether?

Comment: You could remove or unload the projects by right clicking on it and then choose to delete or to unload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ba7zx39%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Be aware that the projects you want to remove aren't referenced elsewhere in your solution

Comment: @Dario, yes everything was ok when modules were unreferenced and deleted from Orchard.Web/Modules. Gracias